# Replace spaces at the end of line in files

Tags: sed

I try to remove the space at the end of line in all Java files. I found such a command from internet but it doesn't work on MacOSX.

```
find ./ -type f  -name '*.java' -exec sed -i '' 's/\s+/\n/g' {} \;
```

I still not figure out why it doesn't work.

Comment: Is it saying any error?

Comment: @sat no any error but didn't functional. I guess the sed regular expression string should be escaped but not how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mac OS X doesn't use GNU `sed` (it uses BSD `sed`), so it doesn't recognize `\s` as 'spaces' (or `+` as 'one or more') by default.  However, the BSD `sed` does support the `-i` option (contrary to another answer), but it requires a backup suffix (which can be an empty string if you're brave and confident your script is correct).

Use:

```
find . -type f -name '*.java' -exec sed -i '' 's/[[:space:]]\{1,\}$//' {} +
```

Or use extended regular expressions (with `-E` in BSD `sed`; you'd use `-r` with GNU `sed`, though it seems to intuit which style of regex you are using):

```
find . -type f -name '*.java' -exec sed -i '' -E 's/[[:space:]]+$//' {} +
```

<sup>The Mac OS X manual page for `sed` refers you to `man 7 re_format` for 'extended regular expressions' enabled by `-E`.  Read with caution; 'extended' is not the same as 'enhanced'!</sup>

Look for one or more space characters at the end of a line; replace them with nothing.  Do it for as many files at a time as convenient (that's the `{}` and `+` in the `find` command; using `;` instead of `+` mandates one `sed` per file).

The `[[:space:]]` notation is POSIX standard and covers blanks and tabs and other white space.  You could use `[[:blank:]]` to deal with only blanks and tabs.  If you're sure you only have trailing blanks (and no trailing tabs), you could replace that unwieldy but precise term with a simple blank (`'s/ +$//'`).  (See POSIX [Regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html).)

Until you've ensured that your script works, I wouldn't use the null backup extension.  You might wreak havoc on your files.

Comment: Great, the first command works fine but the second one doesn't.

Comment: Wah! I missed the -E from the command line — mentioned it, but didn't include it in the sample command.  Sorry!

Comment: It seems still doesn't work even if with '-E' option

Comment: Would this work `find ./ -type f -name '*.java' -exec sed -i '' -E $'s! +$!!g' {} +`

Comment: You were right.  As you can tell, I had not tested the variant.  Yes, your variant would work (I'd use `/` instead of `!`).  I also had `s/[[:space:]]+$//` working.  The `g` suffix is harmless but pointless; there is only one end of line per line, so a 'global' or repeating match doesn't happen.

Comment: The `$'…'` notation is Bash [ANSI C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting).  I'm not sure it changes anything in this example.

Comment: I believe you're correct, probably not needed at all. I had been trying it with `\\\n` as the replacement —  `$'s/ +$/\\\n/g'` (thinking why is it putting two new lines on this replacement! :D)...

Comment: I'm reasonably confident that what's in the answer is now accurate.  I confused myself on one machine (work) with GNU `sed` being on my PATH ahead of system `sed`.  And I think I've now tested everything in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`sed -i` is not supported on Mac OS. If you want to use `sed -i`, I recommend installing GNU coreutils via a package manager like [homebrew](http://brew.sh/).

`brew install coreutils`

For more information regarding coreutils, see `brew info coreutils`.

Comment: `sed -i .bak` is supported by Mac OS X (BSD) `sed`.  What isn't supported is not providing a suffix; you have to use `sed -i ''` to achieve that.